# What does $SU(2)\times U(1)$ really mean?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, yang-mills, electroweak

I know that $SU(2)\times U(1)$ is the product of each element of $SU(2)$ by an element of $U(1)$. But looking at the Lagrangian, such a product exists only in covariant derivatives of Higgs or fermion fields. It turns out that the gauge fields $SU(2)$ and $U(1)$ exist on their own without interacting directly? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups is the simplest possible way to have a $G$ symmetry and an $H$ symmetry. If you wanted the elements generating $G$ to not commute with the elements generating $H$, that would be a semidirect product instead.

Comment: My question was more about the standard model and the Lagrangian. Do SU(2) and U(1) gauge fields interact if no matter or higgs fields are present?

Comment: SU(2) and U(1) fields do not interact with each other at all, except through the matter and Higgs fields coupling to both. SSBreaking via the Higgs fields bridges them, and mixes them together, as they are all broken. Is this what you want to see?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to make sure I'm thinking in the right direction

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105816/2451

Comment: Some useful background here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370573/226902  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/698828/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439380/226902.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement "The symmetry group is $G\times H$" really just means that both $G$ and $H$ are symmetry groups of the theory and these two symmetries do not have anything to do with each other, i.e. they commute. This is because the natural inclusions $G\mapsto G\times \{1\}$ and $H\mapsto \{1\}\times H$ into $G\times H$ commute. Applying some element $(g,h)\in G\times H$ just means "apply $g$, then $h$, or $h$, then $g$, it doesn't matter".

Each object transforms separately under $G$ and $H$ in representations $V_G$ and $V_H$. This is equivalent to saying it transforms in the tensor representation $V_G\otimes V_H$ of $G\times H$.

So instead of enumerating all the independent symmetry groups, one just says that their direct product is "the" symmetry group. It's just language.

However, pay attention to a subtlety in the case of the electroweak interaction: While there *are* independent $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and $\mathrm{U}(1)$ in the unbroken electroweak phase, the $\mathrm{U}(1)$ there is *not* the $\mathrm{U}(1)$ of electric charge, but the $\mathrm{U}(1)$ of [weak hypercharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_hypercharge). The electromagnetic $\mathrm{U}(1)$ sits in the electroweak $\mathrm{SU}(2)\times\mathrm{U}(1)$ via $\phi\mapsto (\phi T_3, \frac{\phi}{2})$ (the 2 might be absent in some scaling conventions), where $T_3$ is the third generator of the isospin $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.